# Can batsman hit the ball after the ball cross the stumps?

Tags: rules, cricket

Can the batsman hit the ball after the ball crossed the stumps?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z4qaGiWt-bo Like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is allowed. There is no rule for this.

Brad Haddin once(two times same match) did this on a free hit. Just because you can't get bowled on a free hit and you get more time when you play after the ball passes the stumps.- **[Video Link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z4qaGiWt-bo)**.

This has hardly happened in International cricket.

Sometimes Upper cuts, unintentionally are hit after the ball crosses the stumps.

Comment: This does seem unfair on the bowler though. Right?