# Can a batsman stand to face a delivery from behind the wickets instead of in front?

Tags: cricket

Are there any rules preventing a batsman from facing a delivery and positioning himself behind the stumps instead of in front?

Comment: See this answer http://sports.stackexchange.com/a/4876/3737

Comment: You certainly couldn't be out LBW, could you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there is anything in the [Laws of Cricket](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/) which specify where a batsman must stand for a ball to be allowed. However, there is the well known "Law of Don't Be Completely Totally and Utterly Stupid" - I fail to see *any* possible advantage that a batsman could gain from standing behind the stumps.

Comment: haha awesome answer. I've been trying it in the nets, and believe it or not it works. If the bowler doesn't bowl on the stumps (and is under pressure to do so) you essentially have a free shot (mainly through point, a cut shot, or even a reverse hook shot. If the bowler puts delivery on the stumps, its easy to block by putting your bat in front of the stumps.

Comment: That may work against amateurs. I wouldn't recommend trying it against Mitchell Johnson.

Comment: More realistically, this tactic is going to fail as soon as you get a bowler who can bowl on the stumps reliably - if your only tactic is "defend", you're going to lose.

Comment: I'll try it in my next international see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly high risk of being given out obstructing the field, I'd think, since he'd be in the wicket-keeper's way.

Comment: Interesting thought. I can't see anything in the Laws which specifies what happens if a batsman and a fielder want to stand in the same place - the batsman would obviously get priority for the usual place in front of the stumps, but what happens if he wants to stand at square leg or something insane like that?

Comment: This would probably also be handled under Law 42, which does discuss actions not covered by the Laws . There are plenty of reasons why having a batsman in an odd position would be a bad idea - likely to get in the way of fielding, making it more difficult to judge runouts, stuff like that. But it's not automatically bad - remember that an injured batsman with a runner occupies a similar position off the pitch. You'd have to consider each situation on its merits.